# Approximate the average response time in M/M/1 queue

Tags: approximation, queueing-theory

In M/M/1 queue system, the average response time is $\frac{1}{\mu-\lambda}$, where $\mu$ is the average service rate and $\lambda$ is the average arrival rate.

Is it possible to approximate the average response time by linear or quadratic functions (other than Taylor expansion and piecewise linear).

Comment: You can also find average response time by using little's law.

Comment: Yes, but I need to approximate it using linear or quadratic, since Little's law will led to a fractional function, which is difficult to optimize.